# What concretly are Public Types in Qt documentations?

Tags: qt

I was starting to learn how to read the documentation on Qt. But there is one part generally located at the beginning of the documentation page which is : **Public Types**, i don't deeply well understand.
Globally, i understand how to use, but what i don't understand is what is a public type in programming and specifically in Qt here ? (I understand when they said in the documentation, properties, classes, public functions...but public types...?)
Thanks in advance for any enlightenment!:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Public types (nothing special wrt Qt on this, btw) are just types declared within the class namespace that have an access specifier `public`, i.e. anyone can use them. E.g. for `QWidget`:

```
class QWidget : public QObject
{
   public:
      ...
      enum RenderFlag { DrawWindowBackground, DrawChildren, IgnoreMask }
      ...
};
```

`RenderFlag` is a public type and can be used to declare variables in your code, e.g.

```
QWidget::RenderFlag flag = QWidget::DrawChildren;
```

Comment: This is not entirely true. Not every exported class / public symbol / method, type, variable with `public:` access means it's **public APIs**, that is, APIs that give source and binary compatibiliy warranty. The rule of thumb is that if it's undocumented in the official docs, then you should be careful as you might be relying on non-public API, which can change at any time. (Example: `Q_GLOBAL_STATIC` has been there since Qt 4.0, but it's going finally public in 5.1, and with **different semantics**.)

Comment: OP is asking about the public API, and I'm saying public API -> public type (in part), which is correct.  It's interesting to know that the converse doesn't hold--I had never thought about that--but it's not directly relevant to the Q or A.

Comment: Ok thanks, if i have well understood : it's like a type(Renderflag in the example above) you put into your class definition , and then you can use it (in a cpp file) by using declared variable syntax.

Comment: @user2305415 Yes, that's exactly it.